# Certificado es requerido vb6

Tags: vb6

estoy tratando de enviar un numero a un Web Service desde vb6 y tengo el siguiente error

Error Ws: -2147012852 - A certificate is required to complete client authentication

Cuando pruebo desde el Postman si tengo respuesta satisfactoria

```
Set objDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set objWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
MsgBox (1)
'Cargar XML
objDom.async = False
objDom.loadXML XmlBody
MsgBox (2)
objWinHttp.Option(4) = &H3300
MsgBox (3)
objWinHttp.SetTimeouts 60000, 60000, 60000, 60000
objWinHttp.Open "POST", AsmxUrl, False
MsgBox (4)

'Crear Cabeceras
objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    
If Me.chkAuth.Value = 1 Then
 MsgBox "Basic " & EncodeBase64("sa"& ":" & "1234")
    objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64("sa"& ":" & "1234")
End If
MsgBox (5)
objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", SoapActionUrl
MsgBox (6)
'Enviar XML
objWinHttp.send objDom.Xml
MsgBox (7)
'Obtener respuesta xml
strRet = objWinHttp.responseText
MsgBox (8)
```

según los MsgBox solo muestran hasta el numero 6, el error estaría en el método send

Comment: vba o vb6? y el certificado que te pide la pagina?

Comment: Hola , el desarrollo es en vb6

Comment: buenisimo.. y la pagina te esta pidiendo un certificado... o algo que te permita hacer un post.. lo estas haciendo bien?

Comment: O no hagas la petición por https, o importa un certificado a "Local Machine" con la [*Herramienta de Configuración de Certificados WinHTTP*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttpcertcfg-exe--a-certificate-configuration-tool) y haz `objWinHttp.SetClientCertificate("LOCAL_MACHINE\RutaATuCertificado")`.

Comment: lo que pasa es que no tiene certificado, si yo hago las pruebas desde Postman si tengo respuesta